# How to handle responses which take more then 5 seconds

Tags: actions-on-google

For the google actions that i am developing some responses are complex and take more than 5 seconds to process.

Could someone please suggest how can this be handled.

Generally i would consider using loading dots and then replacing that message with the result but i don't see any Google Action API for it. Also is there any endpoint to which we could async send back the result later ?

Thanks

PS: I am using Conversation API.

Comment: Maybe send on message saying Hmmm, let me check, give me a few seconds and use placeholder messages

Comment: I am totally new to google actions, could you please elaborate how to use placeholder messages ? and how do they initiate a callback to your webhook ?

Answer (score 1):

We don't really have a good way to handle this right now, but we have a couple of approaches that sorta work based on your needs.

[Notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) are currently available for the Assistant on smartphones, and they're coming for speakers. In some cases, it might make sense to say that you're working on the problem and you'll send a notification when you have it, and then resume the conversation from the notification.

Another approach is to use the [Media Response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) to play a bit of "hold music". At the end of the segment of music, your webhook will get a notice that the music has completed. If you have the result available, you can report it at that time.

Comment: Is there any send endpoint to which we can async send messages ? Like say in case you have a proactive bot ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with links to references for the two possible solutions. Asynchronously sending messages is done through notifications.